# Conexão PHP com Banco de Dados FIREBIRD

Tags: php, firebird

Estou tentando realizar a conexão entre o PHP com o banco de dados FireBird, porém já tentei várias alternativas e não consigo resolver. A mensagem de erro que aparece ao tentar realizar a conexão é a seguinte:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function **ibase_connect()** in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:6

A `extension=php_interbase.dll` já está ativa no php.ini e o caminho extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext" está correto.

Gera esse log também:

> Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_interbase.dll' - Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.

Porém a dll php_interbase.dll existe dentro do diretório C:\xampp\php\ext

Alguém sabe me dizer como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Jogou as dlls do firebird no system ou path do windows?

Comment: Sim copiei lá no System32 também.

Comment: Se o sistema for 64bits vc deve jogar só no system.

Comment: Removi do System32  para o System porém nada mudou.

Comment: Edite o arquivo php.ini e procure por php_interbase.dll descomente essa linha Instala o Firebird, copie o arquivo php_interbase.dll do seu diretório php\ext para o diretório C:\Windows\System32 ou equilavente em 64 bits
Copie os arquivos libeay32.dll e ssleay32.dll do seu diretório php para o diretório C:\Windows\System32 ou equilavente em 64 bits
copie o C:\firebird\bin\fbclient.dll para C:\Windows e C:\Windows\System32 e copie novamente este arquivo, agora com o nome gds32.dll) Reinicie o apache do Apache. Foi assim que eu fiz.

Comment: Marcus, já havia feito exatamente todo esse procedimento anteriormente mesmo assim não deu certo.

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde Amigos. Eu segui todos os passos acima, porém ainda tinha faltado verificar dentro do diretorio do apache o arquivo "php.ini" as extensões. Ou seja, existe 2 arquivos "php.ini", um dentro do diretorio do apache e outro dentro do diretorio do php. Após realizar os procedimentos, funcionou perfeitamente. Espero ter contribuido.